# How do I redirect my aws ec2 instance from http to https?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, https

I am trying to generate a certificate for an ec2 instance so that Jenkins that run over HTTPS.

So far, I have tried:

- http://tteckie.blogspot.ca/2013/02/how-to-install-jenkins-with-ssl-on.html

However, this does not yield the correct outcome.  After executing the instructions, and amending the `127.0.0.1 *.mydomain.com` to the domain name of the instance.

When I got to `https://myinstance.com` the page shows a:

`NOT SECURE: Your connection is not private`

When I go to `http://mystance.com` the url redirects to the https url.

Am I missing something related to generating the certificate?  Should I generate one with AWS Certificate Manager, and add that one to my ec2 instance?

I have also tried, generating a certificate in AWS, and adding this to my domain, this did not work as AWS Certificate Manager does not work with ec2 instances.  I have also tried let's encrypt, however the etc/letsencrypt/live/ directory was not created as expected in the steps.

I went on to trying CertBot (https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntutrusty-apache), but am having some issues with Apache services and starting the service due to errors: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034295/issues-with-running-apache-certbot-due-to-port-already-used-for-httpd-bin

Has anyone successfully been able to run their ec2 server hosting Jenkins over HTTPS? I would like to know how any of the issues above were overcome to successfully implement the SSL.

Comment: If you followed the step under "Generating SSL certificate" then you have created a self-signed certificate, and it won't be trusted in browsers without being manually installed.

Comment: Thanks @S.Dev - do I upload the self-signed certificate to the AWS Certificate Manager?

Comment: Try getting a trusted certificate with Let's Encrypt https://github.com/hughperkins/howto-jenkins-ssl/blob/master/letsencrypt.md

Comment: @kichik I tried using the Let's Encrypt link that you sent, and followed the instructions exactly, however the etc/letsencrypt/live/ directory was not created as expected in the steps.